# ROS groovy update screwed up workspace setup in some cases?

Tags: ros, rosbuild, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After updating ROS groovy from .debs today, the following happens with our software setup:

Source groovy setup:

```
source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash
```

Output of "env | grep ROS":

```
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_TEST_RESULTS_DIR=/home/kohlbrecher/flor_repo/catkin_ws/build/test_results
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=
ROS_DISTRO=groovy
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/groovy/etc/ros
```

sourcing a previously working setup.bash of a rosbuild workspace:

```
source setup.bash
```

results in the following output:

```
kohlbrecher@sk-i7:~/flor_repo/rosbuild_ws$ source setup.bash
bash: /share/rosbash/rosbash: No such file or directory
[rospack] Warning: ROS_ROOT=/share/ros is not a directory
```

Output of "env | grep ROS":

```
ROS_ROOT=/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=[OMITTED FOR BREVITY]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_WORKSPACE=/home/kohlbrecher/flor_repo/rosbuild_ws
ROS_TEST_RESULTS_DIR=/home/kohlbrecher/flor_repo/catkin_ws/build/test_results
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/kohlbrecher/flor_repo/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_DISTRO=groovy
ROS_ETC_DIR=/etc/ros
```

Any ideas what´s going on here? The rosbuild workspace is depending on a catkin workspace. I´ll try reinstalling our setup from scratch next, to see if that solves the problem.

/edit: Tried installing from scratch using our install scripts and these also do not work anymore.

/edit: Related [Q/A here](http://answers.ros.org/question/86981/after-update-getting-error-related-to-ros_root-and-rosbash/)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/86586/ros-groovy-update-screwed-up-workspace-setup-in-some-cases?/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24361 on 2013-10-02

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-10-02**:
Does it help to `rosws regenerate` the setup.bash?

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on 2013-10-02**:
rosws regenerate did not help in my case; I'm seeing the same issue

**Comment by [Calder](https://answers.ros.org/users/4279/calder/) on 2013-10-02**:
I'm seeing this problem too. Since ROS_ROOT has changed from the correct value of `/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros` to `/share/ros`, all tab-completion fails because they rely on rosbash (which needs ROS_ROOT set properly).

As a *very* temporary fix, you can `export ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros` and it appears to fix the problem.

On systems sourcing a Catkin workspace, this problem can be fixed by running catkin_make in the workspace. This will set ROS_ROOT correctly.

**Comment by [barcelosandre](https://answers.ros.org/users/4303/barcelosandre/) on 2013-10-02**:
I did it! I'm just waiting for an oficial solution!

export ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros

export ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/groovy/etc/ros

Thank you!

**Comment by [mboulet](https://answers.ros.org/users/4091/mboulet/) on 2013-10-03**:
I had to delete the workspace devel folder and then run catkin_make to fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution is delete your "devel" and "build" directories, then make a "catkin_make". It will solve the problem.

---

Originally posted by [barcelosandre](https://answers.ros.org/users/4303/barcelosandre/) with karma: 168 on 2013-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2013-10-03**:
yup, regenerating "devel" and "build" on my workspace did the trick. Thanks!

**Comment by [mortenpj](https://answers.ros.org/users/7376/mortenpj/) on 2013-10-13**:
Solved my problem, thanks!